# Going back to normal terminal I/O after closing ncurses window

Tags: c, unix, io, ncurses, curses

In a game I made I create an ncurses window using initscr(), then the user plays the game and when the game ends the program closes the window using endwin() and then prints some statements and gets input from the user using printf and scanf, respectively. My problem is that whenever the game ends scanf always executes before printf. So it waits for a response, and once the user enters the response it prints everything that was before and after the scanf statement. Here is some example code:

```
...

endwin();
system("clear"); /* Clears terminal window */
printf("New high score!\nPlease enter your first name: ");
scanf("%s",name);

... /* file I/O stuff */

printf("Congratulations, %s!",name);
```

As you can see, the printf statement is before the scanf statement but for some reason scanf executes first. I tested the code without an ncurses window and I get the desired result. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: You need to `fflush(stdout);` after your `printf()` call, or terminate the format string with a newline. Nothing to do with curses.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Ok, that worked, but why do I have to call `fflush(stdout)` to get `scanf()` to start working again? From what I gather it basically forces all output streams to update, but I wouldn't normally need that when using `printf()`/`scanf()` (or would I?)

Comment: You don't - you call it to make `printf()` actually write to the screen before your `scanf()` call starts.

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing to do with curses.

This statement is obviously wrong since using *curses* makes a difference, as the question states:

> As you can see, the printf statement is before the scanf statement but
>   for some reason scanf executes first. I tested the code without an
>   ncurses window and I get the desired result. Does anyone know what is
>   causing this?

While it is right that `fflush(stdout)` gives the desired result, that does not answer the question.

What is causing this is presumably the implementation-defined standard I/O characteristic to flush a *line buffered* `stdout` when input is requested (sometimes documented in `man setbuf`), and *curses* setting `stdout` to *fully buffered*, thereby disabling the automatic flush.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about it in the manual page where it discusses [`NCURSES_NO_SETBUF`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_SETBUF):

- to get good performance, most curses implementations change the output buffering from line-oriented to buffer-oriented (so that the library can make larger, more efficient writes)
- because that meant that **all** writes to the standard output would be buffered, it was a nuisance.  ncurses provided an option (the environment variable) to override the buffering.
- that changed in [2012](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20120825), by eliminating the `stdout` buffering altogether to solve a problem with signal handling.
- however, "eliminating" the buffering means that ncurses uses its own buffer.  It'll flush *that* in `endwin`, but doesn't flush `stdout` when switching to/from curses mode.
- a ***few*** applications required modification to flush stdout.

The 2012 change for ncurses was part of the ncurses6 release in [August 2015](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20150808).  The OP's question is in terms of ncurses5.9 (or earlier), since it describes an application where the standard output is buffered.